# Gradient on UIToolbar contained in UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, uikit, uipopovercontroller, uitoolbar, uiappearance

When a UIToolbar is placed inside of a UIPopover, there is a gloss layer that is always drawn on top of it. This gloss layer is drawn regardless of whether or not there is a custom image supplied for the UIToolbar. I have also tried getting rid of this by setting a different shadowImage, but the shadow image was never displayed.

[image]
Here is an example. The UIPopover here has a custom background view that is drawn a straight black to show the problem.

Does anyone know how to either disable this gloss or (better yet) replace it with a gloss image of my own?